# How to save value from TextField in Flutter to use it in other places

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

i am creating very easy app - user will get 4 texfields and he will put there numbers. Then i want to do some math on that numbers.
How is it possible to save that inputs in variables which i could use wherever i want and  in relevant moment?

For now i only created possibility to display it on this class where they were created:

my TextFields look like this (i have 4 textfields: e, f, g and h:

```
var e = '';

TextField(
                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                onChanged: (newVal) {
                  e = newVal;},),
```

And this is button - when i click it i can see inputs

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text('You wrote $d $e $f $g'),
          );
        },
      );
```

But how to save that inputs to variables outside this class?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value from `onChanged` to a state management solution like `StatefulWidget` or `Providers` and so on.

```dart
TextField(
                inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly],
                onChanged: (newVal) {
                  if(newVal != null){
                       context.read<SignUpBloc>().add(SignUpEvent.mobileChanged(mobile: newVal));
                 }

},),
```

This is how we do it in `Bloc`. You can do the same in any other state management solution or even store it locally in `SharedPreferences` as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a TextEditingController inside you class for each field you want to change:

```
class _MyClassWithDataState extends State<MyClassWithData> {
TextEditingController textController1 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController textController2 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController textController3 = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController textController4 = TextEditingController();
}
```

and define on the other class the data you will need:

```
class ClassWithReceivedData extends StatefulWidget {
const ClassWithReceivedData({
Key? key,
required this.text1,
required this.text2,
required this.text3,
required this.text4,
}) : super(key: key);

final TextEditingController text1;
final TextEditingController text2;
final TextEditingController text3;
final TextEditingController text4;

@override
State<ClassWithReceivedData> createState() =>     
_ClassWithReceivedDataState();
}
```

then when you navigate to other page you simple pass:

```
Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new 
ClassWithReceivedData(text1: textController1, text2: textController2, 
text3: textController3, text4: textController4);
```

but if you really need to retrieve data on multiple classes i suggest to create a Controller or a Store class for the data you need an then use an state managment like Provider, Get, Mobx, etc..., to retrieve data whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to use it in TextField? Because i try many solutions, for example 'onChanged: (newVal) {
                  text1 = newVal;}' but it displays error 'undefined name 'text1'

Comment: if your text1 is a TextEdditingController you should use text1.text = newVal;